# How to append custom metabox fields with jQuery in post

Tags: jquery, wordpress, meta-boxes

I am trying to add custom meta box in post programmatically, but js gives an error,the goal is when I click add button,the same text area box is append which 
 was created previously. My code for crating custom metabox in function.php file in twenty seventeen theme is:

```
// including custom js files here
function wptuts_scripts_with_jquery() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myjs.js', array( 'jquery' ));
}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wptuts_scripts_with_jquery' );

// starting custom meta box
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'm_param_meta_box_add' );
function m_param_meta_box_add() {
    add_meta_box( 'm_param_post', 'Box Title', 'm_param_post_meta_box_cb', 'post', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function m_param_post_meta_box_cb( $post )
{
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    if ( isset( $values['m_meta_description'] ) ) {
        $m_meta_description_text = esc_attr( $values['m_meta_description'][0] );
    }
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );

?>

<div id="info"></div>
    <label> Name: </label>
    <textarea rows="1" cols="20" name="m_meta_description" ><?php echo $m_meta_description_text; ?></textarea>

    <button type="button" name="add" id="add">Add</button><br><br>

<?php
} // close m_param_post_meta_box_cb function

add_action( 'save_post', 'cd_meta_box_save' );
function cd_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    // Bail if we're doing an auto save
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;

    // if our nonce isn't there, or we can't verify it, bail
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;

    // if our current user can't edit this post, bail
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    // Make sure your data is set before trying to save it
    if( isset( $_POST['m_meta_description'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'm_meta_description', wp_kses( $_POST['m_meta_description']) );
    }     
}
```

my js code  error is:"**Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at myjs.js:2**"

my js code is:

```
// <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(
            function(){
                $("#add").click(function(){
                    $("#info").append('fname<input type="text" name="name[]">');
                })
            }
        );
    // </script>
```

Comment: Care to share what kind of js error you are getting?

Comment: Edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(
        function(){
            jQuery("#add").click(function(){
                jQuery("#info").append('fname<input type="text" name="name[]">');
            })
        }
    );
```

According to [this](https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/) article, when WordPress’ jQuery is loaded, it uses compatibility mode, which is a mechanism for avoiding conflicts with other language libraries:

> What this boils down to is that you can’t use the dollar sign directly
>   as you would in other projects. When writing jQuery for WordPress you
>   need to use jQuery instead.

Comment: Tryed your code,works perfect, now i have one problem,the text area is appended successfully when i click add button,but it can't saving value for other meta box, only first meta box value is saving,do you have any suggestion for this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure why it doesn't save. Sorry. I suggest to create another question regarding this new problem.

Comment: Check this link: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/23344/why-wont-my-metabox-data-save .

Answer (score 3):

While [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45913878/1260286) is correct, it's worth saying, that you can also do this

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($)
{
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#info").append('fname<input type="text" name="name[]">');
    })
})
```

removing the need of writing `jQuery` everywhere instead of `$`

Answer (score 0):

Even at the beginning, you could remove JQuery and place a "$"

```
$(document).ready(function ($)
{
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("#info").append('fname<input type="text" name="name[]">');
    })
})
```